# Is there a way to have dynamic keys in the MongoDB Output Step of Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

Using - Pentaho Kettle 4.4

Basically I want the values coming in columns from the TABLE INPUT step, as Keys of the mongo document..

Please tell if the question is unclear and I need to add an example.